# iphone: problem in NSMutableArray and NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Dont know whats wrong with this array

```
NSMutableArray *locations=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary *aLocation=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[aLocation setObject:@"26.8465108" forKey:@"lat"];
[aLocation setObject:@"80.9466832" forKey:@"long"];
[locations addObject:aLocation];
[aLocation removeAllObjects]

[aLocation setObject:@"26.846127990018164" forKey:@"lat"];
[aLocation setObject:@"80.97541809082031" forKey:@"long"];
[locations addObject:aLocation];
[aLocation removeAllObjects];
```

but every time I remove all objects from aLocations dictionary those values get deleted from locations array as well.

Please help me in this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour is correct and you can't reuse NSMutableDictionary as you do: NSMutableArray does not copy objects it contains - it just stores **pointers** to those objects. So if an object you added to array changes then array has pointer to that changed object.

To fix your code create NSMutableDictionary instance each time you need to add it to array (or create immutable dictionary if you actually don't need mutable object):

```
NSMutableArray *locations=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary *aLocation= [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"26.8465108", @"lat",@"80.9466832" ,@"long", nil ];
[locations addObject:aLocation];

aLocation= [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                @"26.846127990018164", @"lat",@"80.97541809082031" ,@"long", nil ];
[locations addObject:aLocation];
```

Comment: how to handel this thing then

Comment: Your answer is the only correct one, kudos ;-) P.S: it would also be easy to create a mutable copy of alocation before you add it [locations addObject:[[aLocation mutableCopy] autorelease]]];

Comment: It would probably be more idiomatic to write the code above without the `aLocation` variable — i.e. `[locations addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:…]`.  Personally I’d also be inclined to make a `Coordinate` class with `latitude` and `longitude` properties.

Comment: Yes, aLocation variable is really unnecessary here. But you may need NSDictionaries if you want to save your data in plists

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *locations=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary *aLocation=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[aLocation setObject:@"26.8465108" forKey:@"lat"];
[aLocation setObject:@"80.9466832" forKey:@"long"];
[locations addObject:aLocation];
[aLocation release];

NSMutableDictionary *aLocation1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[aLocation1 setObject:@"26.846127990018164" forKey:@"lat"];
[aLocation1 setObject:@"80.97541809082031" forKey:@"long"];
[locations addObject:aLocation1];
[aLocation1 release];
```

Comment: I prefer Vladimir's answer, because it explains why it happens. Just saying.

Comment: Or you could reuse the same dictionary pointer after the dictionary is added and released.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *locations=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary *aLocation= [NSMutableDictionary initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"26.8465108", @"lat",@"80.9466832" ,@"long", nil ];

[locations addObject:aLocation];


aLocation= [NSMutableDictionary initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                @"26.846127990018164", @"lat",@"80.97541809082031" ,@"long", nil ];

[locations addObject:aLocation];
```